# ForeignKey Reverse relation query

Tags: django, django-models

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher)
    publication_date = models.DateField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

i want to get all Publishers who has published at least one book.

Answer (score 1):

```
Publisher.objects.filter(book__isnull=False).distinct()
```

This does a `JOIN` between the two tables and returns the rows where a book exists. `distinct()` is used to get rid of duplicate `Publishers`.

Comment: not working....
Error: Cannot resolve keyword 'exists' into field. Choices are: ...